# Get the client IP on NextJS and use SSR

Tags: ip, next.js, server-side-rendering, clientip

I'm making a weather app, and I get the client IP with IPIFY, but this loses SSR, or I use SSR and I get the server IP. Someone told
me that I could use the header `x-forwarded-for` and then, with this value, make the weather API call with SSR.

The problem is I'm using only nextjs, no backend here, and second, I don't know how to call or use `x-forwarded-for` in the front to get the client IP.

1. *Is this possible?*
2. *How I can implement that?*

I'm using vercel to deploy the app.

Comment: have u got any solution?

Comment: @ArchanaAgivale No. I finished the project a long time ago. If I'm honest I can't remember what I did, but I definitely didn't get the client IP with SSR

Answer (score 8):

Updated answer as `request.connection` is [deprecated since Node.js v13.0.0](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestconnection). So we should now use `request.socket` instead.

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const forwarded = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];

  const ip = typeof forwarded === 'string' ? forwarded.split(/, /)[0] : req.socket.remoteAddress;

  console.log(ip);

  return {
    props: { ip },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  const forwarded = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"]
  const ip = forwarded ? forwarded.split(/, /)[0] : req.connection.remoteAddress
  return {
    props: {
      ip,
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get them through **getServerSideProps**.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  console.log(req.headers) //see if you have those headers
  return {
    props: {
      headers
    },
  }
}

function Page({ headers }) {
  // Render data...
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, so I used the API Routes and it works, but only got the data from `http://localhost:3000/api`.
    Fortunately I found a solution to the problem, which is basically here: 
[github link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9524#issuecomment-589772756) . The only problem is now that I don't know how to get the IP, because `getData()` which is what is called in the page, does not have req as a parameter, so the header that I occupy is returned undefined.