# Get client IP in getServerSideProps method in NextJs

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to find the IP of the client in getServerSideProps in NextJs. I simply use basic IP found methods but when I call that method in getServerSideProps which always giving me the server IP, not Client IP.

Comment: Have a look at this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66111742/2557263

Comment: I tried but not getting IP address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req }) => {
  const forwarded = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'];

  const ip = typeof forwarded === 'string' ? forwarded.split(/, /)[0] : req.socket.remoteAddress;

  console.log(ip);

  return {
    props: { ip },
  };
};
```

Comment: Curiously this only seems to get the private IP address, even when NextJS is deployed to a non-localhost environment. Curious if anyone else has encountered this and found a solution.