# Nextjs static generation user IP address

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, static-site-generation

**Hi  everyone**. I am working on a page where the content of the page rarely changes(but it can be changed by the user whenever he wants) so I want to make that page to load **fast** and `getStaticProps` does this for me and on any change I can just **revalidate** that route, but cause thats the product page  I want to save the user views on that page. I can save the user who are logged in with their IDs but for non logged in user I have to save their **IP** and now the problem is for the IP I cant use the `staticProps` and I have to use `serverSideProps` which is way more slower than `staticProps`!, what do you guys suggest I should do? (How can I have the best of both worlds?)
I have searched and every answer just suggests that you have to use `serverSideProps`

Similar question on Stackoverflow: (but the approved ans suggests serverSideProps)
[Get the client IP on NextJS and use SSR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66111742/get-the-client-ip-on-nextjs-and-use-ssr)

Comment: You could move the logic to retrieve the IP to an API route, then make a request to it from the client-side to retrieve the IP.

Comment: Tnx @juliomalves I am doing that right now, but it kinda seems hacky, I think middleware should simply just give the req obj that we can get in an api route.